# text over image without using relative position or negative margins

Tags: html, css, text, background-image

I am trying to put text over an image. Something like this (i have changed the background image for propriety reasons)

[image]

The tool/app i am working with has following limitations -

- Using negative margins don't work
- Using position:absolute and position:relative don't work
- fancy stuff like grid and flexbox also dont work

I know i know. You all are thinking "what the heck is it?". But if any one of you used salesforce visualforce email templates, you will know what i am talking about.

So i need to implement it without them. I want the image to retain its aspect ratio as i compress and expand browser window.

When i use background image html tag, i notice that background image does not maintain it's aspect ratio. In full screen mode, it stretches horizontally (actual image i am using has drawing of animated characters in it, which visible look horizontally stretched out)

```
<div style="color:white; background-image: url('images\background.png');max-width: 100%;height: auto;overflow: hidden;background-size: 100% 100%;">
```

But when i use an img tag, image fits the full screen nicely, and maintains its aspect ratio when i change browser window size

```
<img src="images/background.png" style="display: block;max-width: 100%;min-width: 100%;height: auto">
```

So i figured i need to come up with a solution without using background image (or negative margin or position:relative) and somehow get text on it.

I read a post where a guy suggested a hack using tables - 
[How to put text over an image without absolute positioning or setting the image as backbround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829541/how-to-put-text-over-an-image-without-absolute-positioning-or-setting-the-image)

It seems to work to an extend. I need help fixing it. Here is the final code i have-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td rowspan=2 colspan=2><img src="images/background.png" style="display: block;max-width: 100%;min-width: 100%;height: auto"></td>
          </tr>  
          <tr>
            <td rowspan=2 colspan=2><h1 style="margin-top: 5rem;padding-bottom: 25rem; text-align: center; color:white">Thank you for submitting feedback</h1></td>
          </tr>  
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Issue i am facing is if i compress browser window too much, the text float above the blue image, as shown below

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Both text and image are part of table. Is there a way to make sure they stay within table boundaries, so they stay overlapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to align the image on the top in `<td>` element, because its default is middle. That is why it is being aligned that way and giving space above and below.

So, add `vertical-align: top` to `<td>` element.

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```